Calculating the Generator from signature without knowing public key on a curves where ECDLP is easy
I do not know how this question will be received here but it will be an interesting task nevertheless
We all know that an ECDSA signature is $(r, s)$ and is generated in following ways:

Select a random secret key $d$ from the range $]0,n[$ where $n$ is the order of the curve. (This step is not a part of of signature generation, I am writing it here for the sake of fluidity)
Select nonce $k$ the same way as $d$.
Calculate $R=(r, r_y) = kG$ where $G$ was the generator.
Hash a message to $h = H(msg)$ where $H$ is a hash function.
Calculate $s = k^{-1}(h+rd)\mod{n}$
The pair $(r, s)$ be signature.

Nature of curve: Let us say Alice creates an elliptic curve which allows multiplicative transfer or a curve where ECDLP is too easy, like singular curves. Though title mentioned Multiplicative transfer it could be any curve where ECDLP is too easy but brute force isn’t allowed. The curve $y^2 = x^3$ allows so (there is a group law defined on this curve if we exclude the point $(0, 0)$). Any answer to this question can take up this curve.
She share the curve parameters and group order: $a, b, p, n$ where $a, b$ are coefficient in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, the prime field (or finite field) over which the curve is defined, and $N$ be the order of subgroup which is prime with Bob. ($a, b = 0$ if you are taking $y^2 = x^3$ as curve)
Then Alice chooses a point on elliptic curve $G$ the private key $d$. Alice keep this $G$ to herself.
Then Alice start generating a signature. She choose an ephemeral private key $k$ and calculates $k\cdot G = R(r, y_r)$. Thus for a message hash $h$ produces signature $(r, s)$.
She share this signature and message hash with Bob $(r, s, h)$ she also share the coordinate $R(r, r_y)$ while Alice doesn’t share neither her public key nor her generator.
The puzzle is given this info Bob needs to find out the $G$ that Alice used.
A detail that might be useful: Bob has another signature from Alice $(r_2, s_2, h_2)$ but she tells Bob that the signature is faulty instead of $r_2$ she should have used $r_{2c}$ which is the x coordinate of $k_2 \cdot G = R_2(r_{2c}, y_2)$. However, she shares $R_2(r_2,y_2)$

There are two cases:
Case 1: She tells Bob that $k_2 = m + j \cdot k$. (Where we already know as per the answer by @fgrieu how to recover $G$)
Case 2: She doesn’t reveal the relation in case 1 to Bob. Here I think that if ECDLP is easy we would be able to do it.
What I have tried so far?
I thought that getting $r_{2c}$ will be helpful because once we get $r_{2c}$ we can correct signature of Alice as follows:
$$ s_2 = {k_2}^{-1}(h_2+r_2 \cdot d) \\
   s_2 \cdot \frac{r_{2c}}{r_2} = {k_2}^{-1}(h_2 \cdot \frac{r_{2c}}{r_2} +r_2 \cdot \frac{r_{2c}}{r_2} \cdot d) \\
s_2 \cdot \frac{r_{2c}}{r_2} = {k_2}^{-1}(h_2 \cdot \frac{r_{2c}}{r_2} +{r_{2c}} \cdot d) \\
s_{2c} = {k_2}^{-1}(h_{2c} +r_{2c} \cdot d)  $$
Thus getting the correct pair $(r_{2c}, s_{2c}, h_{2c})$.
Once we have these pairs we can derive $G$ as follows:
$$G = (\frac{s_1 r_{2c}}{h r_{2c} - h_{2c} r})R - (\frac{s_{2c} r}{h r_{2c} - h_{2c} r})R_{2c} \tag{1}$$
But the problem still stands because we cannot get $R_2$ until we know $G$.
Another thing I thought of is:
As the order is prime we can have a $G’$ such that $k_1 \times G’ = R_1$ and there should exist $i$ such that $i \times G = G’$ but it require us to know $i$ which seems impossible.
I know on secure curve it is hard, or impossible, to do this but is it equally hard to do so on Curves that allow multiplicative transfer or the curves where ECDLP is too easy like singular curves?
[Edit: I have significantly modified the question because earlier question was too ambiguous]

I guess that [A] when Alice makes a second signature, she restarts at step 2 (as in standard ECDSA). [B] In the second signature Alice made some error at the second step 3. [C] The $r_2$ we get is the one used at the second step 5. [D] Alice reveals $m$ and $j$ of $k_2=m+j\cdot k$ where $k_2$ is what she used in the second step 5 (if she did not, that info $k_2=m+j\cdot k$, or/and $s_2$, would be pointless). Hint: When we have two valid (hash, signature) pairs, we can typically reduce $G$ to 4 possible values that we can compute using linear algebra. Is this homework?

@fgrieu [A] Exactly $d$ is chosen only once [B] Yes she made an error in calculating what we call ephemeral public key whose $x$ coordinate is used in signature as $r$ value [C] Yes she used the faulty $r_2$ [D] Absolutely True. She revealed the $k_2$  she used in step 5 but incorrect $r_2$

@fgrieu On this being a homework problem, yes an no. This is a self assignment around ECDSA. I do so during winter vacations as evident from the fact I am active here mostly during winters. Even after trying a lot I cannot get it. It would be highly helpful if you can  answer.

Another way we can think about it is the second $(r_2, s_2, h_2)$ (what I have called faulty) signature is not actually faulty but should be true for another Generator $G'$ because curve's order is prime. But here comes (maybe, as I couldn't understand) the problem of Generator again.

Further hint: any (hash, signature) that's valid w.r.t. a public key is bound to pass the ECDSA signature verification. That gives a linear relation linking $R$ for that signature, $G$, and the public key. When and if we have two such valid (hash, signature) for the same public key, we can combine the corresponding relations to eliminate the public key. Now if only we had the $R$ for each signature... Suggestion: when you figured it out, answer your own question. [Apocryphal note: this hint assumes "getting the correct pair $(r_{2c}, s_{2c}, h_{2c})$" but we do not quite do that.]

@fgrieu But the public key isn’t same in both case as $s2$ is faulty for $G$ because $k_2 \cdot \neq R_2(r_2, y_2)$. How can recover algorithm produce same public key? Also Was I right in the comment “Another way we can think about…” and explore that?

@fgrieu I think I wouldn’t be able to do it. Can you please consider answer it? I have been trying this for 3 days with no results. I am not getting your hints also, how can $(r_{2c}, s_{2c}, h_{2 c})$ be rebuild if we don’t know $k_2$ or $k_1$?

The question (case 1, or/and version 4 as clarified by this comment) boils down to: we know the curve, $r$, $s$, $h$, $r_2$, $s_2$, $h_2$, $m$, $j$, and prime $n$, with
$$(r,r_y)=k\times G\tag1\label{fgr1}$$
$$s=k^{-1}(h+r\cdot d)\bmod n\tag2\label{fgr2}$$
$$s_2={k_2}^{-1}(h_2+r_2\cdot d)\bmod n\tag3\label{fgr3}$$
$$k_2=(m+j\cdot k)\bmod n\tag4\label{fgr4}$$
We want $G$, and know about it only that it's on the curve and has order $n$. Beyond their range we have no clue about $d$, $k$, $k_2$, $r_y$, or the public key $d\times G$.
Note: I use $\times$ for point multiplication in $(\ref{fgr1})$ and $\cdot$ for integer multiplication in $(\ref{fgr2})$ and $(\ref{fgr3})$ because it helps to make these operators clearly different. I add $\bmod n$ in $(\ref{fgr4})$ because in the point multiplication of the question's step 2 the scalar multiplier is in range $]0,n[$, however the following works equally well if we assume $k_2=(m+j\cdot k)$ without modular reduction, as in the question's statement). I deliberately leave messages aside, because only their hashes matter in the question. I guess the width of the hash is at most the bit width of $n$ (because otherwise the question would deviate from ECDSA by not truncating wider hashes).
We can deduce more from the statement "We all know that an ECDSA signature is..". This implies that things including the curve are such that steps 1 to 6 in the question match what ECDSA signing involves (even though some ECDSA steps are omitted in the question).
It must be that the curve is over a prime field $\mathbb F_p$ assimilated to integers in $[0,p)$: otherwise conversion of $r$ from point X coordinate at the question's step 2, which is in the field, into an integer $r$ at the question's step 5, would involve an arbitrary conversion prescribed for ECDSA, but the question has no clue. The curve's equation must thus be the one given in ECDSA for a curve over a field of prime order, that is, for known $a$, $b$, and known prime $p$
$$y^2\equiv x^3+a\cdot x+b\pmod p\tag5\label{fgr5}$$
Additionally I'll assume that the $r$ in the question's steps 2, 5 and 6 carry the same information even though in the definition of ECDSA, §4.1.3 signing operation substep 3 there is an explicit reduction modulo $n$. Perhaps the question deviates from ECDSA, and removes this modular reduction. Or perhaps $n>p$ as in secp224k1, thus the modular reduction can't change $r$. Or perhaps $n\lesssim p$ as in most other prime curves actually used (e.g. secp256k1, secp256r1) thus it's vanishingly unlikely that the reduction modulo $n$ changes $r$ (this has probability at most about $2/\sqrt p$ per Hasse's bound, since ECDSA over prime fields uses curves of prime order, equivalently of cofactor $h=1$).
Update: And I'll assume that $s\ne0$ and $s_2\ne 0$. One reason is that actual ECDSA retries at the question's step 2 should the result of step 5 be $0$. Also a signature $(r,s=0)$ reveals the private key $d$. Another is that such signature does not verify.

$(\ref{fgr2})$, $(\ref{fgr3})$, $(\ref{fgr4})$ form a system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns $d$, $k$, $k_2$ in the field $\mathbb F_n$, and unless we are very unlucky we can solve it and get these unknowns. Actually for the last step we are most interested in $k^{-1}\bmod n$, and it can be obtained on the line of:

We eliminate $d$ from $(\ref{fgr2})$ and $(\ref{fgr3})$ to get the implicated
$$k\cdot r_2\cdot s+k_2\cdot r\cdot s_2\equiv h\cdot r_2+h_2\cdot r\pmod n\tag6\label{fgr6}$$
We eliminate $k_2$ from $(\ref{fgr4})$ and $(\ref{fgr6})$ to get the implicated
$$k\cdot(r_2\cdot s+j\cdot r\cdot s_2)\equiv h\cdot r_2+h_2\cdot r-m\cdot r\cdot s_2\pmod n\tag7\label{fgr7}$$
Now if $h\cdot r_2+h_2\cdot r\not\equiv m\cdot r\cdot s_2\pmod n$ (which is very likely) we get from $(\ref{fgr7})$
$$k^{-1}\bmod n\;=\;(h\cdot r_2+h_2\cdot r-m\cdot r\cdot s_2)^{-1}\cdot(r_2\cdot s+j\cdot r\cdot s_2)\bmod n\tag8\label{fgr8}$$
where the inverse on the RHS is modulo $n$ and can be computed e.g. using the (half) extended Euclidean algorithm.


$(\ref{fgr2})$ implies $(r,r_y)$ is coordinates of a point of the curve (notice that $k\times G$ can't be the point at infinity because $0<k<n$ and $G$ has order $n$, and all points of the curve except the point at infinity have coordinates). The curve's equation $(\ref{fgr5})$ further tells that
$${r_y}^2\equiv r^3+a\cdot r+b\pmod n\tag9\label{fgr9}$$
That leaves us with only two possible values of $r_y\in[0,p)$ that we can compute using Tonelli-Shanks. We thus have only two possibilities for the point $(r,r_y)$.
Because $0<k<n$ and $n$ is the prime order of $G$, $(\ref{fgr2})$ is equivalent to
$$G=(k^{-1}\bmod n)\times R\quad\text{with}\quad R=(r,r_y)\tag{10}\label{fgr10}$$
Now we put in $(\ref{fgr10})$ the value of $k^{-1}\bmod n$ we got from $(\ref{fgr8})$ and that lets us compute the two possible points $G$ by point multiplication. These $G$ differ only by their Y coordinate, with the two possible values summing to $p$.
Note: if we had got a correct second signature instead of a faulty one and the hint $(\ref{fgr2})$, we'd end up with four possible $G$. And there could in theory be more $G$ if a modular reduction from the $r$ of the question's step 3 to the $r$ of it's step 6 changed $r$.

Update for the question version 5, option 2: we don't get the hint $(\ref{fgr4})$. With so little clue about $k_2$ (we only know that it's not $0$ modulo $n$) there's very little to learn from $(\ref{fgr3})$. We only learn that $d$ can't be $d'\;=\;-{r_2}^{-1}\cdot h_2\bmod n$.
With so little known about $d\bmod n$ (we only know that it's neither $0$ nor $d'$) there's very little to learn from $(\ref{fgr2})$. Assuming $h\bmod n$ is neither $0$ nor $-r\cdot d'\bmod n$ (which is very likely), we only learn about $k^{-1}\bmod n$ that it can be neither $h^{-1}\cdot s\bmod n$ (because $d\ne 0)$ nor $(h+r\cdot d')^{-1}\cdot s\bmod n$ (because $d\ne d')$.
We are left with the problem of finding $G$ from $(\ref{fgr1})$ with only that known about $k^{-1}\bmod n$. That allows $G$ to be nearly any point of the prime order subgroup of the curve, except the point at infinity (because it has order $1$, not $n$) and four points made impossible by the two impossible values of $k^{-1}\bmod n$. It's easy to compute these impossible $G$, just as we reconstruct $G$ in the above section.
I conclude there are $n-5$ possible $G$ in case 2 under the very likely assumptions stated.
The reasoning stands without invoking that the DLP is hard, thus stands without hypothesis on the curve, which I suspect are in the problem statement as an invitation to a snipe hunt.

Thanks for the answer fgrieu. I have a follow up question. What if we didn't know that $k_2 = j + m\cdot k_1$. OR in another words:  $j$ and $m$ Alice gave are: $j = \frac{h_2r_1 - h_1r_2}{s_2r_1}$ and $m = \frac{s_1r_2}{s_2r_1}$ Will we still be able to recover $G$?

Got it in such a case the multiplicative transfer property comes handy. We can always know $i$ such that $i × R(r, y_r) = R_1(r_1, y_1)$. This $i$ holds irrespective of generator we choose so that "faulty" signature (whose $r_2$ is calculated using $G'$)  will become valid if we multiply signature with $i^{-1}$ because it eventually will modify $k_1$ to $k_{1c}$ for which $k_{1_c} \times G = R_1(r_1, y_1)$. Am I right?

I don't know what "multiplicative transfer property" means, and it does not Google.  Suggestion: write it down in the question. But my intuition is that whatever it is, if it lets us find $G$, then a curve used by ECDSA must not have this property. I have had to assume more than enough  properties that the curve must have (base field $\mathbb F_p$ with prime $p$, prime order curve, and even $n>p$ if the thing is to actually match ECDSA).

Multiplicative transfers allow MOV attack more on http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/transfer.html

I am asking for curves where ECDLP is easy, like very easy, say for curve $y^2 = x^3$, where it is not even ECDLP just simple DLP. I am editing question to match these details.

“Finitely many points” Well I don’t think so the generator should be a point such that $k \times G = R$. Doesn’t matter what public key it comes up with $d \times G$.

Fgrieu and @madhurkant why both of you are so obsessed with generator. Hint: 1. No ECDSA signature, given $r$ must be $x$ coordinate of a point on curve, is invalid. 2. Every signature can have a generator $G_f$ such that it verifies a signature for any Arbitrary public key. 3. Focus on mathematics that is foundation of ECC, not just ECDSA.

@esteregg: in the question "faulty" (not "invalid") is in the sense that $r_2$ was not computed correctly. Plus in ECDSA, $r$ is not the X coordinate of a point of the curve, which is a field element. Instead it's an integer (or formally a bit representation of it). That integer is obtained by reduction modulo $n$ (the prime order of a subgroup of the curve) of a potentially other integer, itself obtained by converting per some rather arbitrary convention the field element that is the X coordinate of a point of the curve. And that point is bound to belong to said prime order subgroup.

@fgrieu See example OP has given if ECDLP is very weak I prefer using the term dLog. You are again talking in cryptographic terms. Allow me to tell you again, if its okay as per rules here. The second signature is valid for $G_f$ and first one is valid for $G$. We can find $t$ such that $t×G = G_f$

Thanks @fgrieu for all the help and bearing me (a person who edits his question all the times). I got it. But I still hope there could be some way.

@esteregg Can you please expand your hint. If we do not know $G$ and $G_f$ how can we derive $t$ at all (on a side note I have tried this but everything boils down to having no information around $G$ and $G_f$. Please add an answer if you can.

@madhurkant 1. Well I have expanded it as much as possible. 2. If a direct answer is provided what will you learn? 3. For what purpose you want this knowledge? I better understand that it isn't a "self assignment". You have come too far in your "self assignment" now reveal your true purpose and I will reveal the way forward.
